# Can you indent in GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

Is it possible to indent (or start a new line) in GridView? So something like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 
7 8 9 10
```

So it would be empty space after grid 6 until next line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_row and android:layout_column properties allow you to stick any view into whatever row and column you want.

In this case you would put 7 into row 2 and column 0.

Comment: Hmm, I guess there isn't an easy way to do this dynamically

Comment: Dynamically as in I have a GridView of unknown number of items. And I want to index an item (but don't necessarily know what row it's currently in).